# Additional languages are shown in supported languages, although only one language is supported in iOS

Tags: ios, localization, app-store-connect

I recently uploaded an app to the app store. During earlier stage it required to be supporting 5 Languages and I added the strings file for it. But retracted later with language support in current version need to be supported in English only. After successfully pushing the app, the iTunes is showing supported languages as English + 4 additional languages. Can I edit the settings to show support language only as English? Do I need to delete localizable strings for other languages and submit again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it will pick localization support from **project settings**. As many languages one adds to that setting, that many strings files will be generated. I would suggest to use English in project settings and remove the other languages locations files.

Refer below image: in the **Localizations** section, there should be only those languages which app is going to support.

[image]

Comment: You are right, I added 5 languages in the settings. Do I need to upload binary again after changing this setting.

Comment: Yes, because app will get knowledge from settings provided by developer only. As of now, app will be considering that your code support multiple localization, as per settings you have setup.

Comment: Before uploading you should have test your app on device, with various locales. There should be proper testing.

Comment: Ok, I figured out if there is a way to edit the language settings in iTunes, but didn't have any luck.So uploading the binary as a new update is the only solution? The localizable strings are empty, didn't know it would cause such an issue.

Comment: I guess this is the only solution, but this time before uploading test on local device with various locales.